# Rewrite git history to modify a file

Tags: git

To remove a large unwanted file from all of git history you can use `filter-branch` to rewrite the index (the list of files in the repo) of each commit so the file was never added.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/offending_file.wav" --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But what if I want to keep the file but make it a lot smaller (e.g. imagine if an icon was accidentally stored as a huge image). I tried this approach:

First add a replacement file to git's database

```
HASH=`git hash-object -w /tmp/replacement.png`
```

Also note the file we want to replace

```
FILE="path/to/icon.png"
```

Now filter the index as follows: first check the file exists at this commit:

```
git cat-file -e :"$FILE"
```

If so remove it from the index:

```
git rm --cached "$FILE"
```

And finally add a reference to our replacement with the same filename.

```
git update-index --add --cacheinfo "100644,$HASH,$FILE"
```

Putting it all together:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "if git cat-file -e :$FILE ; then git rm --cached $FILE ; git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644,$HASH,$FILE ; fi" --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

This seems to work and doesn't print any errors that are *too* scary. However, no matter how many `git gc` and prune commands I try the original blob still exists in the repository. Even if I clone the repo to a new place it still exists.

I suspect it is because the remote refs, and the `original` refs which `filter-branch` creates still point to the old tree, so the original file is still referenced.

I did try removing them all with a hack like this:

```
for REF in `git show-ref | cut -c 42- | grep original` ; do git update-ref -d $REF ; done
```

And the same for `remotes`, but the blob is still there.

So my questions:

1. Is there a way to see why a blob isn't garbage collected? I.e. which parents objects in the graph point to it?
2. Is there a non-hacky way to remove the `originals` refs (and maybe the remotes) - including all branches and tags?
3. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Is that the case that there are _many_ commits containing this large file, such that manually rewriting the history isn't a realistic possibility?

Comment: Yeah something like 100 commits.

Answer (score 1):

Aha I've done it! I think.

Here are the extra steps. First it's a good idea to note the hash of the blob you want at the start so you can check if it exists with

```
git cat-file -t 949abcd....
```

Ok so first I cleared the reflog, since it still has a reference to the original clone:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
```

Next I removed the origin remote, since it still has a reference to the original tree. I guess if you *push* the new hashes (probably need to force push) then this step will be unnecessary and the file should be eventually GCed anyway.

```
git remote rm origin
```

Next I removed the `original` refs (that `filter-branch` creates). I didn't find a less hacky way:

```
for REF in `git show-ref | cut -c 42- | grep original` ; do git update-ref -d $REF ; done
```

Finally, garbage collect. I'm not sure whether `--aggressive` is required but `--prune=now` definitely is because otherwise `git gc` only garbage collects *old* unwanted objects, for safety.

```
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

After all these steps `git cat-file` reports that the blob is gone! I haven't experimented with pushing the result back to origin (after you re-add it), and I'm not 100% sure which of the above steps are necessary, but this seemed to work so far.