# How to rewrite git history to remove a modification to a file

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274481/rewrite-git-history-to-modify-a-file/62955531#62955531) but with the availability of filter-repo I wonder if there is a better approach now.

I have a large-ish repo with a few problematic commits that I want to clean up via rewriting history (I will not be pushing back to origin, this will be the new 'master' repo going forward, the original will remain as-is in read-only mode in perpetuity).

There are a number of commits where a file has been replaced with a large binary file. There are corresponding commits that fix the problem by re-instating the non-binary file.

Given a set of these commit pairs, I could conceivably use rebase -i to manually fixup the commits. But there are many commits, and I want a scriptable solution. Can filter-repo be used to accomplish this?
I can imagine using --commit-callback and checking the filenames in the file_changes, but I also need to check the size to determine if this commit is one of the problematic ones.

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback '
commit.file_changes = [ c in commit.file_changes
                        if not (c.filename == b"myfilename" and
                               <somehow check size of blob here>) ]
'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, as [in this issue](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/45), write a python program like [`black_history.py`](https://gist.github.com/JacobHayes/9c86cc650c17a776f4a592fe0b2e7645) which would:

- call filter-repo
- with a commit-callback
- which has the hability to!

  - check the content filenames
  - dump the right ones on disk, where you can check the size

That is:

```py
    for change in commit.file_changes:
        if change.blob_id in blobs_handled:
            change.blob_id = blobs_handled[change.blob_id]
        elif change.filename.endswith(b".py"):
            # change.blob_id is None for deleted files (ex: change.type=b'D')
            if change.blob_id is None:
                assert change.type == b"D"
                continue
            # Get the old blob contents
            cat_file_process.stdin.write(change.blob_id + b"\n")
            cat_file_process.stdin.flush()
            objhash, objtype, objsize = cat_file_process.stdout.readline().split()
```

If `objsize` is too big, you would remove that blob from the current change.

Comment: Something like this seems to be the right approach. Thanks